# Comment out multiline log statements using perl one liner regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl one-liner that works when log statements are on a single line:

```
find  -type f -iname "*java" | xargs -d'\n' -n 1 perl -i -pe 's{(log.*((info)|(debug)).*)}{//$1}gi'
```

But trying to modify this to work on multiple lines is tricky. I know that the `s` modifier will match newlines, but how do I get it to comment out subsequent lines (i.e. up to `;` assuming the log string doesn't have it)?

I'm fine with a solution that makes multi-line log statements into single-line log statements too. I'll also accept C-style comments (though it would be nice to find a solution for C++ style comments).

(Don't tell me to turn off logging. Anyone who's actually tried that will realize how brutally complicated that is in non-trivial applications.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a general idea (please adapt to your case...)

```
...perl -i -p0e 's{(log.*?((info)|(debug)).*?;)}{ $1 =~ s!^|\n!\n//!gr }gsei'
```

where:

- `.*?` instead of `.*`  to behave non-greddy
- `-p0e`  to process the full text as a single record
- `$1 =~ s!^|\n!\n//!gr` to make extra processing of internal newlines

Please test it before application...

Comment: Oh, 2 & 3 are newidioms to me and look very useful. I'll follow up if this doesn't fulfil my needs.

Comment: Hmmmm, it's commenting out lots of import lines. I'll have to take a closer look a bit later to debug it.

Comment: if you provide an example with some problematic cases I can try to give alternatives...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators), `start .. stop`:

```
perl -i -pe 's!^!//! if /log.*(info|debug)/ .. /;/'
```